# How to update in sqlite using INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have some data to be updated in SQLite which comes from multiple table. SELECT SQL works fine but UPDATE SQL doesn't work. I don't want to use subquery to update each record separately. Is there any way to update multiple record in SQLite using joins?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer.

This is done by subquery and no need to update each record individually.

```
 SELECT records from tbl1 inner join tbl2 ON tbl1.col1=tbl2.col1 inner join tbl3 ON tbl2.col3=tbl3.col1 inner join tbl4 ON tbl4.col3=tbl2.col1 where condition; UPDATE query UPDATE tbl1 SET col1= (select col3 from tbl2,tbl3,tbl4 where tbl1.col1=tbl2.col1 AND tbl4.col3=tbl2.col1 AND tbl2.col3=tbl3.col1)
```

Comment: Would you please edit your question if you found the answer? Right now nobody can make use of your question. If you don't want to include your code and your solution, consider closing the question.

Comment: Select query was **SELECT records from tbl1 inner join tbl2 ON tbl1.col1=tbl2.col1 inner join tbl3 ON tbl2.col3=tbl3.col1 inner join tbl4 ON tbl4.col3=tbl2.col1 where condition;**   UPDATE query **UPDATE tbl1 SET col1= (select col3 from tbl2,tbl3,tbl4 where tbl1.col1=tbl2.col1 AND tbl4.col3=tbl2.col1 AND tbl2.col3=tbl3.col1)** worked